# Android Volley - Getting No Response using StringRequest to XML API

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I get no response when request string to **XML API**. Here's the code :

```
String url =  "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"
String url2 = "http://api.json.request"
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String _response) {

                Log.d("json=>",_response);
                res = _response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // Error handling
        Log.d("jsone=>", error.toString());

    }
});

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

i have tested it using **Google API (url2)**, but it's fine. Maybe Android Volley run too slow when try to get response, but seeing log i didnt get it at all.

The Log when initiate request :

```
01-28 10:57:05.253 21424-21424/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:26387334
01-28 10:57:05.353 21424-21424/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi D/pre=: 0
01-28 10:57:05.433 21424-21424/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi W/ImageLoader: Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at first.
01-28 10:57:05.463 21424-21470/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 503K, 11% free 24699K/27632K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
01-28 10:57:05.483 21424-21470/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 29.898MB for 3686416-byte allocation
01-28 10:57:05.543 21424-21424/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi W/ImageLoader: Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at first.
01-28 10:57:05.573 21424-21547/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 173K, 10% free 28324K/31236K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
01-28 10:57:05.573 21424-21547/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 33.438MB for 3686416-byte allocation                                                                               </note>
01-28 10:57:05.643 21424-21424/com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42485428 time:26387720
```

Comment: Did you see any logs in the Logcat? did you get any error?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed i dont get any error / warning related to this xml problem...

Comment: Attach your logcat when you initiate this request

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I have attached the logs, the url of XML is http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml`

Comment: The log example you have provided covers less than half-second period of time. A Response, or VolleyError could have taken longer than that. Do you not see any log with you "jsone=>" tag at any time?

Comment: @JasonGrife please see 8th line of the logs, i just get `</note>` from `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml` and i dont get anything from "jsone=>"

Comment: I don't know what's going on with you logs. My recommendation is to add breakpoints on your Log.d() lines in both OnRespionse and OnErrorResponse and then run debugger. That should help answer what's going on.

Comment: Are you downloading images at the same time? Maybe the response is taking long because there are other downloads. If you're downloading images, then first try and stop the image download and see whether the JSON download works.

Answer (score 0):

please ensure that you add **permission** in `manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: please tag this question with meta-tags to categorized your Question. @ankit aggarwal